# Component display twice on view in react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> Function 1 Which returns JSON array.

```
function allPlans()
{
    var all_plans = {
            'Option1' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"5 Per Month"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"5 Per Month"}                            
            },
            'Option2' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"}                            
            },
            'Option3' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"}                            
            },
            'Option4':{
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Full Access"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"Full Access"}                            
            },
            'Option5' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"3 Per Month"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"3 Per Month"}                            
            },
            'Option6' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"1 Portfolio"}                            
            },
            'Option7' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"1 Per Month"}                            
            },
        }

    return all_plans;
}
```

> Another function "rendercolumn()" to return plans view.

```
function rendercolumn()
{
    const options = allPlans();
    var isrowclass = false;
    var getrowclass = "";
    const plansMap = Object.keys(options).reduce((acc, title) => {
        if (props.planname == 'free')
        {
            var plans = options[title]["free"];
        }
        else if(props.planname == 'premium')
        {
            var plans = options[title]["premium"];
        }
        else if(props.planname == 'vip')
        {
            var plans = options[title]["vip"];
        }

        Object.keys(plans).forEach(plan => 
        {
            if (!acc[plan])
            {
                acc[plan] = [];
            }

            if(isrowclass == true)
            {
                isrowclass = false;
                getrowclass = plan_item_gray;
            }
            else
            {
                isrowclass = true;
                getrowclass = plan_item;
            }

            acc[plan].push({
                title,
                status: plans.status,
                text: plans.plantext,
                rowclass: getrowclass,
            })
        });

        return acc;

    }, {})

    return (
        <div>
          {Object.keys(plansMap).map(plan => (
              <Column key={plan} data={plansMap[plan]} />
          ))}
        </div>
    )

}
```

> After that called component "Column"

```
const Column = ({data}) => (

    <div>
        {data.map(option => (
          <div className={option.rowclass}>{option.text}</div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
```

And at the last I have called **"{rendercolumn()}"** function to display the data on view.

Now in all above code I'm getting rows as expected, but it showing details twice.

> I'm getting result like:

[image]

> I want result like:

[image]

What changes needs to be done in above code?

Comment: Simply use map instead of reduce.

Comment: trying map instead of reduce :( getting errors

Comment: See following code, in this you will get object key name and its value as well to render your 
component.Object.keys(all_plans).map(data => {
 console.log(data, all_plans[data]);
});

Comment: in the reduce function i have used acc object to push data. How can I use same in map function? In the map function i'm getting multiple array node of same object I need only one.

Comment: Map function still displaying twice..